# Python match the string of one column to the substring of another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I need Python code that takes the text in column x and loops over column y and searches for the substring values x within each value in Y. My example is below. IF possible, I would like it to print the value of the match and the name in a dictionary or someway I convert it to a Pandas dataframe with a value for each column. I'm fairly new at this keep getting errors. My code and error is below.

```
matches=['cat','bat','fat']
names=['turtle','bigcats','hfat1']

for x in matches:
    if name.str.contains(x) == 1:
    print(name)
```

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Your source is incomplete. From the error message, you're not using plain Python lists, but likely Pandas frames. Also, indentation is incorrect. Please provide a minimal _complete_ example.

Answer (score 4):

Since you tagged this question as pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

matches=['cat','bat','fat']
names=['turtle','bigcats','hfat1']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':names,'Matches':matches})
print(df)
```

Starting dataframe:

```
  Matches     Name
0     cat   turtle
1     bat  bigcats
2     fat    hfat1
```

Use `str` access with `contains` and regex created by `join`:

```
df.loc[df.Name.str.contains('|'.join(df.Matches)),'Name'].tolist()
```

Output:

```
['bigcats', 'hfat1']
```

Answer (score 2):

With Numpy's `find`

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import find

matches = np.array(['cat', 'bat', 'fat'])
names = np.array(['turtle', 'bigcats', 'hfat1'])

i, j = np.where(find(names[:, None], matches) > -1)

print(matches[j], names[i], sep='\n')

['cat' 'fat']
['bigcats' 'hfat1']
```

Wrapped in a Pandas series

```
pd.Series(dict(zip(matches[j], names[i])))

cat    bigcats
fat      hfat1
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unsure about your question, but does this do what you want?

```
matches=['cat','bat','fat']
names=['turtle','bigcats','hfat1']

for x in matches:
    for name in names:
        if x in name:
            print(name)
```

Be aware that if you're using a `pandas.Series` and do `series.str.contains(s)` that will check whether `s` is in *each* value in `series` - this will return another `Series` with `True` or `False` for each. That's why you're getting the error - you're comparing a `Series` with an `int`, which doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is what you're looking for? "name" is undefined as your second array is "names" and your "if" statement should look like below to find a value in an array:

```
matches=['cat','bat','fat']
names=['turtle','bigcats','hfat1']

for x in matches:
    if x in names:
        print(names)
```